# Display week dates on label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying weekdays on a label when user click on the date. The code for the same is given

**C#**

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     DateTime input = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
     int delta = DayOfWeek.Sunday - input.DayOfWeek;
     DateTime firstDay = input.AddDays(delta);

     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
         Label2.Text += ((DateTime)(firstDay.Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)))).ToShortDateString() + "  ";
 }
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Calendar1" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" />
```

Now the problem is that whenever I click the dates on the label should get overwrite but each time its writing dates next to the previous one already present. Ideally it should be over writing on the existing dates.

The second issue is that I want to display and get the week numbers as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is set the label2 text to empty in the SelectionChanged event i.e.

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            DateTime input = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
            int delta = DayOfWeek.Sunday - input.DayOfWeek;
            DateTime firstDay = input.AddDays(delta);

            Label2.Text = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                Label2.Text += ((DateTime)(firstDay.Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)))).ToShortDateString() + "  ";
        }
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712143/show-week-numbers-in-aspcalendar) covers your question about week numbers.

Comment: Got it working thank you...but what about the 2nd issue. I am still stuck in that

Comment: Did you read the [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712143/show-week-numbers-in-aspcalendar) I referenced, that has a full source code example.